# Is it secure to use window.origin with postMessage?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, crossdomain

When using postMessage it's important to define a targetOrigin to ensure we don't leak data to other sites.

It's equally important to check the origin when receiving a message to prevent other sites from triggering our scripts.

But, if we're just expecting to do this on our own domain, is there anything wrong with:

```
targetWindow.postMessage({message}, window.origin);
```

--

```
window.addEventListener("message", e => {
  if (e.origin == window.origin){
    //Trigger something
  }
});
```

Comment: Note, this was originally posted on Stack Overflow, but it was suggested that I post here for a more appropriate audience! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64128018/is-it-secure-to-use-window-origin-with-postmessage

Comment: I agree this should be here. You are clearly asking for the security considerations and not for (just) a code solution.

Answer (score 1):

> `targetWindow.postMessage({message}, window.origin);`

So line transmits the windows origin (e.a. The page domain loaded)
As the origin data for the post message. This is fine.

> `window.addEventListener("message", e => { if (e.origin == window.origin){ //Trigger something } });`

This would check that the message received is from the same origin as this window. This is slightly more problematic, if someone hosted this code on same other domain it would still work. (If that’s not a concern than it’s fine). A more secure strategy would be to replace the `window.origin`   with a `const ORIGIN = “<domain>;` and `if( e.origin === ORIGIN)`. This would make it impossible to redefine the origin mod processing of the javascript (or at least after the const) and would make the check do a type check and value check. (Instead of a typebended value check)

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: Hey, many thanks for this response, sorry for slow reply. Can you explain why you describe the latter as problematic? It's not the done thing to start all JS scripts with `if(window.origin !== "mydomain.com") throw "Problematic error :/";` What makes these listeners risky, where my other js code isn't?

Comment: Basically your code will react to all messages send to it. From any source. Without any validation. That’s slightly problematic imho.

Comment: As I understand it, it will react to any message sent to it that *claims* to be from the same domain. I don't understand why hard coding the domain changes anything here?

Comment: Well. Read up on XSS and other similar problems as to why. But “hard” code in the domain to prevent someone from Chargeing it. Especially when you consider add-ons you simply can’t assume this check will work as you intended.

Comment: Thanks LvB, I know a fair bit about various methods of XSS but still can't see why a hardcoded domain would make a difference. Can you either elaborate or direct me to somewhere that does? Sorry if I'm being pedantic, but the point of the question was to either get solid reasons why this wasn't a good idea, or if no solid evidence could be given then I was going to assume that it's safe to use.

Comment: I do not mind you asking for more clarification, (or being pedantic) it just means I was not clear enough for you. You should never assume anything is safe. Especially from a security standpoint. If the domain is variable (not a constant) it can be modified by a third party. Making this check redundant and allowing a malicious payload to just do whatever it wants. I will suggest you try and understand my points before dismissing them, solid evidence that you asked for does not exist as such (most is definitionally so, not evidently so).

Comment: So are you saying that someone could change window.origin to "https://evil.com" before I check: e.origin == window.origin? If that's right, can you confirm how you think this could be achieved without the attacker already having full control of javascript?

Comment: Basically your ignoring the following “The origin is not guaranteed to be the current or future origin of that window” from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage that e.origin is under complete controle of the sending party, that can hang anything in the origin part of that object.

Comment: "Note that this origin is not guaranteed to be the current or future origin of that window, which might have been navigated to a different location since postMessage was called" is referring to event.origin (or e.origin in our examples), not to window.origin.